# Align first line to the next line

Tags: html, css

I just can't figure out how to do this simple thing,

**WEB PAGE: [PAGE](http://cp.wgaming.net)

Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxd5zkfy/)**

Can you please go on this page and see...
The **Recent activity** section, has text after the name and arrows, and that text is not looking good, it's going below the image and that's what I want to fix, I need it to be a little aligned with the first line, and that might make it look good, I can't even test how will it look like that, and if it does not look good like that, please help me make it look good...

It look too *glitchy* and I want it to look better, I am a noob in *CSS* so please help...

I added a *Fiddle* to make it clear, Here is the code you might need to edit...

```
    <li>
        <img src="assets\images\avatar_100x\163.png" class="w35" alt="Tony Toomport">
        <span class="user font-slab">Tony Toomport </span>
        <span class="subject"> has been given rank 7 (OG) in Los Santos Maddogs (14) by Leader Tyson Maddog (rank 9).</span>
   > /* I wan't this ^ to look good when there are 2 lines(on small screens), because it currently goes under the image and does not look good... */
        <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 hour's ago</span>
    </li>
```

**Please Help me at least tell me what should I do to make the second line aligned with the first lines starting...**

THANKS

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Create some fiddle for us.

Comment: provide a picture or a fiddle

Comment: You won't be able to change tabs but still, you don't need it...

Comment: @Paulie_D it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` and `position: absolute;` to do this.

And add some style, for example `margin-top: 8px;`

```
.subject{
  display: inline-block;
  position : absolute;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Fiddle : [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ienzo/uxd5zkfy/2/)